# Inputting Comma Delimited Data from a .txt when Variables that are Entirely Empty Need to be Read in as Strings

Tags: string, csv, input, stata

I have some .txt files of delimited data.  I first read each one in, save it to a temporary file, and then append the temporary files to another to create the entire data set.

The problem is that some variables in some of the .txt files are blank whereas they are strings in some of the other.  When they are blank, it processes the blank values as bytes, and makes them compatible in the appending process.

I've been using `insheet` to input the data.  Is there a way to `insheet` the data such that I specify that I want the variable to be a string?  I looked into `infile` but I did not see a way to deal with delimited data, which might account for why I'm having problems applying it here.  I also looked into `tostring` and `generate`, but that generates a new variable only when the variable is not a string.

I'm looking for a general method because I'd like to do this via loops as there are multiple data sets (and lots of variables within each one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess "compatible" in your question should be "incompatible".

You want certain variable(s) to be string, regardless.

First off, it is immensely easier to deal with the unpredictability after reading in the data, so don't focus on which command to use for that.

Second, contrary to your implication `tostring` can deal with the uncertainty.

```
tostring myvar, replace
```

will replace `myvar` as string if `myvar` is numeric and leave it be if it is already string. 
But if the variable is changed from a numeric variable that is all missing, the result will be the string "." again and again. Whether you need to do something to change that is not clear to me.

FWIW, I wrote `tostring` to work this way.